# Deserialize BigDecimal in scala with json4s return empty list

Tags: scala, bigdecimal, json4s

Given this json:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "details": [{
        "tax": [{
            "amount": 1
        },
        {
            "amount": 2
        }]
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to reading it in this way:

```
lazy val amounts: List[BigDecimal] = parse(json) \\ "amount" \ classOf[JDecimal]
```

But it's giving me an empty list, while using `JDouble` like this:

```
lazy val amounts: List[Double] = parse(json) \\ "amount" \ classOf[JDouble]
```

It's giving me the correct list.
How can I directly read a list of `BigDecimals`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly you can solve it by using `extract` method with target `type` for this conversion, like:

```
  val amounts = parse(json) \ "details" \ "tax" \ "amount" 
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  val decimals = amounts.extract[List[BigDecimal]]
  > List(1, 2)
```

**Explanation:**

When read `amounts` it's element type is `JInt` not `JDecimal`,

```
val amounts = parse(json) \ "details" \ "tax" \ "amount"
> JArray(List(JInt(1), JInt(2)))
```

as you can see it's `JInt` type for the `amounts`.

and for extracting by `class` type:

```
 def \[A <: JValue](clazz: Class[A]): List[A#Values] =
    findDirect(jv.children, typePredicate(clazz) _).asInstanceOf[List[A]] map { _.values }
```

it's `predicating` by `clazz`, but the `amounts`'s element type is `JInt`, so it's will return an empty list.